# Automatic object to array conversion

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I am using Ember-Data on client side & ruby on server side to fetch data from postgres SQL database,

When I do `App.Person.findAll(App.Person)` from the server side I am returning an array of ruby hash objects

Now when I do `console.log(typeof App.Person.findAll(App.Person))` it prints `'object'`

But When I use it in handlebars as,

```
//Here I set in my ArrayController this.set('content', App.Person.findAll(App.Person));
{{#collection contentBinding="content"}} 
  Name: {{view.content.name}}
{{/collection}}
```

It prints all the names as if we are iterating over an array of objects, does ember converts the object to array ?

Comment: what does that printed object have?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the printing, it's going as expected, the doubt being how is it iterating the content when the type of content is of Object..getting me ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using
`App.Person.findAll(App.Person).toArray()`
to see the array of records, and
`record.toJSON()` to see a record as an object; i.e.

```
App.Person.findAll(App.Person).map(function(record) { 
    return record.toJSON();
}
```

The result returned by findAll() is a `RecordArray`:
https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L378

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/record_arrays/record_array.js

`RecordArray` extends `ArrayProxy`, which inherits the `toArray()` method.

Comment: I think I did not properly compose my question, I understand toArray() method does get the array list, My doubt was that even though we don't use .toArray() on App.Person.findAll(App.Person) Handlebars still is able to iterate over it, I had a peek into the handlebars helper definition but couldn't find anything which converts the "object" returned by App.Person.findAll(App.Person) to an array for iteration

Comment: The `collection` and `each` helper take the path to the object as a string; in order to see what happens in detail I suggest you set a break point in the code for that Ember.Handlebars.helper (`collection` in your case: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/helpers/collection.js#L142) and debug it to see what it does; I was unable to grasp the details when I debugged it.